Riverpod provider save after widget not mounted
Edit! This seems to only be happening on hot restart, but but when I do flutter run.
On my flutter app,  I download some constants from my server on the splash screen. The app doesn't start until these downloads are completed. On the splash screen I download like this, on initState() :
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {

      await getAllLocations().catchError((error, stackTrace) {
        log("getAllLocations ERROR: $error");
      }),

}

Future<void> getAllLocations() async {
    GetAllLocationsApi getAllLocationsApi = GetAllLocationsApi();
    List<MyLocation> locationList = await getAllLocationsApi.getAllLocationsApi() ?? [];

    ref.read(locationListProvider.notifier).addLocations(locationList);
  }

Here is my provider:
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class LocationList extends _$LocationList{

  @override
  List<MyLocation> build() {
    return[];
  }

  void addLocations(List<MyLocation> locationList){
    state = [...state + locationList];
  }

}

Now the problem is, when I save the provider, with this line:
ref.read(locationListProvider.notifier).addLocations(locationList)
I am getting this error:

This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context
(and should be considered defunct). Consider canceling any active work
during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the
State is still active.

Now, I understand this error is because I am trying to update the UI after the widget was removed. However, in this case, the provider I am saving doesn't affect the UI at all at this point in the app. Only later, I reference the data that I fetched and saved here.
How can I save the data in this provider, and not get this error? Am I saving the data in an incorrect manner?
Thanks
